# Upload only images through Opencart File option

Tags: php, image, file, opencart2.x

I am using **Opencart 2.0.3.1**.

While order product customer have to `upload image`. For this I added **File option** for the product. But using the **File option** user can upload any type of file. I want restrict to upload only `image files(jpg,jpeg,png etc).`

Here is the button code:(**catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl**)

```
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
            <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
              <label class="control-label"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
              <button type="button" id="button-upload<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> <?php echo $button_upload; ?></button>
              <input type="hidden" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="" id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" />
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

And I am using no external modules.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this option from admin panel. which is given instruction below..

```
1- open admin panel

2- click on setting submenu inside system tab.
```

[image: important image added]

```
3- click on server tab then you can see "Allowed File Extensions:" option. then you can set as you wish.
```